# What does 'reload' do in this case?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import utils; reload(utils)

from utils import *
```

Why does it need load twice? 'reload' is not a built-in function. Right?

Comment: reload is a built-in function in python 2 https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does 'reload' do in this case?

That depends on what `utils` does... For example, if importing `utils` has a side-effect, then that effect will take place again.

---

Also note that using `reload` in any production code is definitely something that you want to avoid. The main reason that `reload` exists is for interactive use ...

- load module
- Test it out and see a bug
- Edit module
- Reload module
- Test it out
- ...

Comment: Why does the 'side-effect' need to take place again?

Comment: @user697911 -- I don't have any idea why the side-effect would need to happen again :-).  I don't even know if `utils` _has_ a side-effect.

Comment: After "edit" a module, you have to run the module again, and when you run the module, the first "import utils" is executed AGAIN. Why do you need to reload(utils) to get the effect?

Comment: @user697911 -- You needed the first import to get a reference to reload.  Each import first checks to see if the module was _already_ imported.  If it was, then it doesn't get imported _again_.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to find out is to check the [`reload` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.reload), which says:

> 1. *Python modules’ code is recompiled and the module-level code reexecuted*, defining a new set of objects which are bound to names in the module’s dictionary. The init function of extension modules is not called a second time.
> 2. As with all other objects in Python the *old objects are only reclaimed after their reference counts drop to zero*.
> 3. The *names in the module namespace are updated* to point to any new or changed objects.
> 4. Other *references to the old objects* (such as names external to the module) *are not rebound to refer to the new objects and must be updated in each namespace where they occur if that is desired*.